# diffoff on all buffers

Tags: buffers, vimdiff

Occasionally I have a stray forgotten buffer in which I ran `:diffthis`. Later when I run `:diffthis` on some unrelated buffer that second buffer is immediately and unintentionally highlighted with the diff. At this point I don't know which buffer is the first in which `:diffthis` was run and I don't know how to `:diffoff` on that buffer.

How do I solve this? Can I simply `:diffoff` on all buffers, even buffers not in any window?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this:

```
:bufdo diffoff
```

The [`:bufdo`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#%3Abufdo) command runs a given command on all buffers. It works by cycling through all buffers and executing the command, so you will end up on the last buffer.

#### Caveat

From the help:

> Note: While this command is executing, the Syntax autocommand event is disabled by adding it to 'eventignore'.  This considerably speeds up editing each buffer.

This usually has the undesirable side-effect that syntax highlighting will be turned off in many buffers. When you switch to a buffer affected by this, you can simply run `:edit` (or `:e` for short) to trigger the Syntax autocommand that normally gets triggered.